# WPF weird behaviour: The SelectedValue is set right BUT then ist reset to NULL

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, null, nullreferenceexception

I am binding a `ListBox` to a `List` in the ViewModel named `FilmeSerienListe`. `SelectedItem` is set when `ismouseover = True`. The `SelectedItem` of the ListBox is bound to a Property in the ViewModel named `SelectedFilmSerie`.

This means when the mouse is over a particular ListBoxItem, this ListBoxItem is selected and its value bound to `SelectedFilmSerie`. BUT this does not seem to work very well, because the `SelectedFilmSerie` Property is for some reason always `NULL`. So, I debugged the App to see what did go wrong – Now the weird behaviour – `SelectedFilmSerie` is in fact NOT the WHOLE time NULL.

At first – when the mouse is over a ListBoxItem – the `value` parameter is set to the right Object, and it is NOT NULL, BUT then when I go further with my debugging this `SelectedFilmSerie` Property is recalled and NOW the value parameter is NULL, which make the `SelectedFilmSerie` Property also NULL.

**WPF:**

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding FilmeSerienListe}"
         SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedFilmSerie}">

   <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">

         <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
               <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                  <ContentPresenter />
               </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
         </Setter>

         <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
                     Value="True">

               <Setter Property="IsSelected"
                        Value="true" />

                  </Setter.Value>
               </Setter>
            </Trigger>
         </Style.Triggers>
      </Style>
   </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

**C#**

```
private IEnumerable<FilmeSerien> _filmeSerienListe;
public IEnumerable<FilmeSerien> FilmeSerienListe
{
    get => _filmeSerienListe;
    set
    {
        _filmeSerienListe = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged();
    }
}

private FilmeSerien _selectedFilmSerie;
public FilmeSerien SelectedFilmSerie
{
    get => _selectedFilmSerie;
    set
    {
        Trace.WriteLine(value != null ? "Value is NOT null" : "Value is NULL");
        _selectedFilmSerie = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

**Debugger:**

ismouseover = True:
[image]
4xStep Over:
[image]
1xStep Over:
[image]
4xStep Over:
[image]

**Output:**

The sec the mouse entered the ListBoxItem, I get `Value is NOT null` and the sec the mouse leaves the ListBoxItem, I get `Value is NULL`

[image]

**More details:**

The ListBox is a list of cards bound to `FilmeSerienListe` with the datatype `IEnumerable<FilmeSerien>` each `ListBoxItem` is a card which is a representation of a `FilmeSerien`.

A card contains several Properties that are in a Property with the datatype `FilmeSerien`. Like: Titel, Img, **Vote** and other. `Vote` is an `int` datatype Property.

Looks something like this:

[image]

**Problem:**

Every Time I hit a star to vote a movie. I get a NullReferenceException because the `SelectedFilmSerie` is null.

**WPF For star:**

```
<Viewbox>
   <materialDesign:RatingBar Value="{Binding Vote}"
                              Orientation="Horizontal"
                              Foreground="SkyBlue"/>
</Viewbox>
```

Comment: Please clarify.
Is Selected cleared while the cursor is still over the selected item?
Or when you go beyond its borders?
The second is the correct operation of the trigger.
With stop points, this will be difficult to verify.
Since when switching to the Debugger Window, the cursor automatically leaves the element and the trigger is reset.
Make an output to the Debugger console (Debug.WriteLine (...)) and track it.

Comment: @EldHasp see my Output

Comment: Well, that is how the trigger for the property `IsMouseOver` is working

Comment: Setting the trigger to IsSelected is not the same as selecting a list item in the ListBox UI.
It is difficult to understand the reason by your codes.
But from your explanation, you are confusing these two different actions.

Comment: For example, when you type a "star" in an extended element, the cursor is no longer over the ListBox element.
And, accordingly, the trigger on IsSelected is reset.

Comment: @EldHasp Yeah I thought the same, but I cannot figure anything out on how to solve this. Do you have any idea how I can resolve it? Thankss

Comment: @EldHasp BTW I removed the ismouseover Trigger and just selected the Item by clicking on the item and then clicked the star, but this didn't work either :(. I got the NullRE.

Comment: If you have shown the entire ListBoxItem template, then such a template will not work.
Completely remove the `<ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>` block and then check.
Explain what you wanted to achieve by such overriding the ListBoxItem template?
Perhaps I can show you how to correctly implement this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you need to select the ListBox element not by clicking, but by hovering the mouse over it.

To be honest, it does not even occur to my head for what this might be needed.
I asked in the comments to clarify the purpose of such an implementation, but you didn't answer.

But if, I understood your question correctly, then it is implemented like this:

```
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="listBoxItemStyle" TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Trigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsSelected">
                                    <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="True"/>
                                </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </Trigger.EnterActions>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
  </Window.Resources>
    <Grid VerticalAlignment="Center" >
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding FilmeSerienListe}"
                 SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedFilmSerie}"
                 ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource listBoxItemStyle}">
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
```